# Return 2 date variables in the same return?

Tags: java

I have to make a code where, I have to split a string line.
The problem is that I need to pass 2 strings, one to dates and the other to times.
I can do it, but how do I make the return, return the 2 variables if I don't join them? with "+"?

```
String[] Division = linea.split(",");
        LocalDateTime fecha = Conversion(Division[0],Division[1]); //12/06/2017,12:34
```

This is the code where I created the date and time but I don't know how to return it,

```
private static LocalDateTime Conversion(String fechas , String Horas){
        LocalDateTime FechaConvertida =  LocalDateTime.parse(fechas,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        LocalDateTime HoraConvertida = LocalDateTime.parse(Horas,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
        return ;
```

Comment: You could return a `Map<String, LocalDateTime>` or a `List<LocalDateTime>`

Comment: Return a array of `LocalDateTime` or create a return object with properties for each depending on your needs or convert each one individually.  I'd probably also use `LocalTime` and `LocalDate`.  If you need to combine them, you can use [`LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate, LocalTime)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalTime))

Comment: change : LocalDateTime Conversion,  for List<LocalDateTime> and return : FechaConvertida+HoraConvertida ?

Comment: why not merge the date (`LocalDate`) and the time (`LocalTime`) to ONE `LocalDateTime`? (and use `toLocalDate()` and `toLocalTime()` to obtain each component where needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that you're converting a seperate "date" and "time" value, I would use `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` to parse the inputs and then combine them into a `LocalDateTime` result, for example...

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        // Note 12/06/2017 does not match the format of dd-MM-yyyy
        LocalDateTime fecha = Conversion("12-06-2017", "12:34");
        System.out.println(fecha);
    }

    private static LocalDateTime Conversion(String fechas, String Horas) {
        LocalDate FechaConvertida = LocalDate.parse(fechas, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        LocalTime HoraConvertida = LocalTime.parse(Horas, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
        return LocalDateTime.of(FechaConvertida, HoraConvertida);
    }
}
```

which prints...

```
2017-06-12T12:34
```

Answer (score 3):

You can return only one object. So, if you need to return more than one object you can use one of these approaches:

1. Define a class to represent 2 dates:

```java
public class FechaConvertida {
    
    public LocalDateTime FechaConvertida;
    public LocalDateTime HoraConvertida;
    
    public FechaConvertida(LocalDateTime fechaConvertida, LocalDateTime horaConvertida) {
        super();
        FechaConvertida = fechaConvertida;
        HoraConvertida = horaConvertida;
    }    

}
```

And then return a FechaConvertida instance:

```java
private static FechaConvertida Conversion(String fechas , String Horas){
        LocalDateTime fechaConvertida =  LocalDateTime.parse(fechas,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        LocalDateTime horaConvertida = LocalDateTime.parse(Horas,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
        return new FechaConvertida(fechaConvertida, horaConvertida );
```

2. Return an array of LocalDateTime:

```java
private static LocalDateTime[] Conversion(String fechas , String Horas){
        LocalDateTime fechaConvertida =  LocalDateTime.parse(fechas,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        LocalDateTime horaConvertida = LocalDateTime.parse(Horas,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));

        LocalDateTime fechaArray []= {fechaConvertida, horaConvertida}; 
        return fechaArray;
```

3. Return a List:

```java
private static Collection<LocalDateTime> Conversion(String fechas , String Horas){
        LocalDateTime fechaConvertida =  LocalDateTime.parse(fechas,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        LocalDateTime horaConvertida = LocalDateTime.parse(Horas,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));

        Collection<LocalDateTime> dates = new LinkedList<LocalDateTime>();
        dates.add(fechaConvertida)
        dates.add(horaConvertida)
        return dates;
```

I change the name of the variables in order to lower the case of the first letter cause as a good practice, variables names don't start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a `Map` of LocalDateTime, see code below as an example:

```java
String[] Division = linea.split(",");
LocalDateTime fecha = doConversion(Division[0],Division[1]).get("fecha");
LocalDateTime hora = doConversion(Division[0],Division[1]).get("hora");


private static Map<LocalDateTime> doConversion(String fechas , String Horas) {
    LocalDateTime fechaConvertida = LocalDateTime.parse(fechas, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    LocalDateTime horaConvertida = LocalDateTime.parse(Horas, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));

    Map<LocalDateTime> localDateTimeMap = new HashMap<>();
    localDateTimeMap.put("fecha", fechaConvertida);
    localDateTimeMap.put("hora", horaConvertida);

    return localDateTimeMap;
}
```

btw, in Java, method and variable names start with lower case as Standard (actually it's called camelCase)

Comment: Since the OP is converting a seperate "date" and "time" value, it "might" be better to use `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` and the combine them into a single `LocalDateTime` value ... but more context would be required

Comment: @MadProgrammer correct! I am just using the given code, trying to minimize changes

Comment: Yep, not saying your approach is wrong, based on my understand of the question been asked, this would be suitable, but I'm just looking at what the OP is "actually" doing 

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, I understood that from your suggestion... cheers!

Comment: i try with your code but i appear error  :with map